# jQuery .on() with specific form, input, and data output

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to do this:

I have a bunch of buttons in a form. They all have unique names. Whenever someone CLICKS on any of these, in this specific form, I would like to submit an event (SUBMIT_IMAGES) and just get the $_POST variable or data of the clicked button and not of the entire form.

Something like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="IMAGE_FORM">
<input value="" type="button" name="CLICKHERE1" class="IC10" onclick="SUBMIT_IMAGES();">
<input value="" type="button" name="CLICKHERE2" class="IC10" onclick="SUBMIT_IMAGES();">
</form>

$('#IMAGE_FORM:input').on('click', SUBMIT_IMAGES);

function SUBMIT_IMAGES(event)
{
    var DATA = new FormData(event);
}
```

first, how can I specify .on event in a specific form, on an input in that form... is this correct?

```
$('#IMAGE_FORM:input').on('click', SUBMIT_IMAGES);
```

Secondly, how can I do something like:

```
function SUBMIT_IMAGES(event)
{
    var DATA = new event.target.FormData();
}
```

but insead do a events.target.INPUTDATA(); kinda thing

Comment: What does _"just get the $_POST variable or data of the clicked button"_ mean? Your buttons have neither a value nor a data attribute.

Comment: This gets all the form data from the entire form: it works fine, var DATA = new FormData($('#IMAGE_FORM')[0]);, BUT I want it to be specific, get targeted FormData from the input that is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try AJAX ?

If your form looks like :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="IMAGE_FORM">
    [many inputs]
    <input value="" type="button" name="CLICKHERE1" class="IC10" onclick="SUBMIT_IMAGES();">

    [many inputs]
    <input value="" type="button" name="CLICKHERE2" class="IC10" onclick="SUBMIT_IMAGES();">    
</form>
```

Then you can try something like this :

```
$('input[name=CLICKHERE1]').click(function(){
    var fields = '{ ';

    $('#IMAGE_FORM').each(function(){
        if($(this).name() == 'CLICKHERE1')
        {
            fields += ' }'// close json
        }
        else
        {
            fields += // feed fields var
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        // Do some stuff
    });
});
```

Then you can send datas using AJAX.
Of course, if you have to post images or other files it'll be quite difficult.